# Credential on AWS SES

Tags: java, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

In http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-java.html there is an explanation on how to send emails via AWS-SES. It refers to access_key and secret_key. But what I have is SMTP Username and SMTP Password that I have generated on the portal.

Currently my code is as follows:

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(credentials);
client.sendEmail(request);
```

The constructor for AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient takes AWSCredentials but NOT the smtp credentials. Any idea on how to use the SMTP credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JavaMail as the transport for Amazon SES SMTP. [Instructions and sample code](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-smtp-java.html) for using the SMTP endpoint are also provided in the Amazon SES documentation.

Use the SDK if you intend to send email via the Amazon SES API.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use below code to send mail through SMTP 

 InternetAddress[] parse = InternetAddress.parse(toAddess , true);

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        //Add properties
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");

        // Create a Session object to represent a mail session with the specified properties.
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

        // Create a message with the specified information.
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromemail));


        msg.setRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,  parse);


        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setContent(body,"text/html");

        // Create a transport.
        Transport transport = session.getTransport();

        // Send the message.
        try
        {
            logger.info("Attempting to send an email through the Amazon SES SMTP interface to "+toAddess);

            // Connect to Amazon SES using the SMTP username and password specified above.
            transport.connect(smtpHost, port, smtpuserName, smtpPassword);


            // Send the email.
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
           logger.info("MessageID"+ msg.getMessageID());

            logger.info("Email sent!");
            return msg.getMessageID();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("The email was not sent. Error message: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close and terminate the connection.
            transport.close();
        }
```